# If a user gets 30 up votes on his answer, will he get remaining 100 reputation tomorrow?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

We all know that

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day.

So if a user gets 30 up votes on his answer today, he can only get 200 reputation today. But what about the rest 100 reputation, will he get 100 reputation tomorrow or 100 reputation are gone for good?

Comment: You should really read the questions tagged `faq`. Everything you need to know is pretty much already present there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> so if a user gets 30 up votes on his answer today, he can only get 200
>   points today. But what about the rest 100 points, will he get 100
>   points tomorrow or 100 points are gone for good?

Gone for good. But note that this has nothing to do with the tag score, you'll still get 30 regardless of the reputation.

Also it's not *exactly* correct that the max reputation is 200 per day, you can reach more if you have an accepted answer or won a bounty..

It doesn't make sense to earn 200 points today, and 100 tomorrow. If that's the case, then why not winning the 300 points today?..